# Using Facade Design Pattern | Drawbacks/ Solutions/ Suggestions

Tags: java, design-patterns

Each method in `Facade Object` is combination of several other methods exposed in several interfaces. Over the period of time this object will also grow as we will come to know about different operations that can be achieved by combining different interfaces available in complex system and its method.

My question is simple:

1) It is a better option to go ahead with Facade or do we have some other option available? because as we increase the number of methods to accommodate each new operation in Facade object, it also becomes complex. *A possible solution that I can think of is to create one more Facade*

2) Also, is there a limit-on methods exposed by facade when we will say it become complex?
`Update`: *my analysis says stop adding more method to a Facade if it is making hard to understand and rethink your design*; `is that it`?

Comment: As the question is quite open, I recommend Head First Design Patterns ch. 7, where a lot of best practices are explained. And to 2) - the limit is when it starts to be confusing for your and your co-programmers.

Comment: @LastFreeNickname: Which part you don't understand? please let me know I will try to add that too.

Answer (score 3):

Since your question is very abstract, it's hard to answer it in a way that is guaranteed to be good for the specifics of what you're writing.

As far as I can tell, the question you're asking is really, if you have

```
interface A {  public void a(); }
interface B {  public void b(); }

class ABFacade {
   private final A a = ...
   private final B b = ...
   public void ab() {  a.a(); b.b(); }
}
```

then is that useful or not?

The answer is going to depend on

- The problem domain - how well defined is it?
- How you name things - will people understand it?
- Code reuse - is there more than one thing that will ever need to call a facade method?

I don't think there is a single right answer - at least not with specific examples.  It also depends on what the purpose for using this pattern is - better code reuse?  Fewer sets of duplicate code that does something complex?  Creating choke points all code that does X must pass through?  Clarity for other developers?  The answers to that question profoundly affects what your code should look like.

I can suggest some general things that might help result in something useful:

- If a facade method will only be used in one place, it probably does not deserve to be in the facade - if it the code only has one client, it probably makes more sense to do all the steps inline
- Can some operation on the facade be given clear naming?  Would the result be more intuitive to use than writing out everything the facade does?  If so, then that probably should be on the facade

At the end, it's just a pattern.  If it lets you write smaller, better or more reliable software, use it;  if it doesn't, don't bother.

Comment: useful answer, but as you have highlighted in your answer too that *ab* is an operation that you have created just to do one operation and then there can be multiple combinations like this. My questions was around those lines when you identify new operation and think of adding new method to your facade obj that makes it heavier. I think Facade is not going to help than.

Comment: @Tim Boudreau `If a facade method will only be used in one place, it probably does not deserve to be in the facade.` Not in terms of DI, it will be very useful for aggregate service: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/. And doing `all the steps inline` is a violation of SRP and violates TDD, thus reducing maintainability.

Comment: I also don't agree with `If a facade method will only be used in one place...`. That's like saying don't make a method if it's going to be called from one place.

Comment: Sure, for DI that may matter.  I'm assuming "for a human looking at an interface they've never seen before and trying to figure out what they should care about".  In that case, creating an API that only has one caller which was already written is not nice to people who will have to read the code later.  That can work for DI, since it does not need to be human-friendly - it will be called by a machine via reflection.